# <!DOCTYPE html> missing in Selenium Python page_source

Tags: python, django, selenium, html5lib

I'm using Selenium for functional testing of a Django application and thought I'd try `html5lib` as a way of validating the html output. One of the validations is that the page starts with a `<!DOCTYPE ...>` tag.

The unit test checks with `response.content.decode()` all worked fine, correctly flagging errors, but I found that Selenium `driver.page_source` output starts with an `html` tag. I have double-checked that I'm using the correct template by modifying the title and making sure that the change is reflected in the `page_source`. There is also a missing newline and indentation between the `<html>` tag and the `<title>` tag.

This is what the first few lines looks like in the Firefox browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>NetLog</title>
    </head>
```

Here's the Python code.

```
self.driver.get(f"{self.live_server_url}/netlog/")
print(self.driver.page_source
```

And here's the first few lines of the print when run under the Firefox web driver.

```
<html><head>
        <title>NetLog</title>
    </head>
```

The page body looks fine, while the missing newline is also present between `</body>` and `</html>`. Is this expected behaviour? I suppose I could just stuff the DOCTYPE tag in front of the string as a workaround but would prefer to have it behave as intended.

Chris

Comment: I think this is known issue, page resource wouldn't show that. Why do you want that comment anyway ?

Comment: I wanted it because the `strict=True` validation in html5lib expects it.  If that's the way it works I guess I'll just use the hack I mentioned.